# Regular expression to match first element

Tags: regex

My data strings can be in this format

1.

```
{"name":"Lokesh","accountNumber":"3044444444","city":"New York"}
```

2. 

```
"{\"name\":\"Lokesh\",\"accountNumber\":\"3044444444\",\"city\":\"New York\"}"
```

3. 

```
"\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Lokesh\\\",\\\"accountNumber\\\":\\\"3044444444\\\",\\\"city\\\":\\\"New York\\\"}\""
```

Basically, a JSON object that can be stringified any number of times or it can be similar looking string for example
`"hello"="world"`

I have written regex as

```
/\\*".*account.*\\*":\\*"(.*?)\\*".*/g
```

But it matches `New YorK`

But I want to match the first element i.e. `3044444444`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you consider using a JSON parser?

Comment: My use case doesn't satisfy the JSON parser. I wouldn't know if the sting is json parsable or not. @anubhava

Comment: how would it? you specified that you want to capture something BEHIND the word „account“. But your text appears BEFORE that word…

Comment: oh my bad, I want to capture `3044444444`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `\\*".*account[^,]*\\*":\\*"((.*?)\\*)".*`
see: https://regex101.com/r/vb2rx4/1

Then only thing changed is that i replaced `.` by `[^,]`.  A `.` will match anything, and `[^,]` will match anything but a comma.

Comment: On second time reading your question, you wanted to return the `name`, so this will return `Lokesh`: https://regex101.com/r/l8SN0r/1  (regex: `\\*".*name[^,]*\\*":\\*"((.*?)\\*)".*`)

Comment: oh my bad, I want to capture 3044444444

Comment: `.*` is redundant here

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with a negated character class:

```bash
"account[^"\\]*\\*":\\*"([^"\\]*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKzely/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `"account`: Match `"account`
- `[^"\\]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that is not `"` and `\`
- `\\*":\\*"`: Match `":"` with optional `\`s
- `([^"\\]*)`: Our match, which is 0 or more of any char that is not `"` and `\`, captured in group #1